# How to get the end of entry of the first column in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table like this:

```
Sequence
2089697
2089738
2089838
2090368
2090400
```

I want to have another column

```
Sequence; EndSequence  
2089697; 2089737
2089738; 2089837
2089838; 2090367
2090368; 2090399
2090400; null
```

The EndSequence will be the end of the next record of the Sequence column.

Comment: what version of sql server you are using?

Answer (score 3):

FOR SQL SERVER 2005/2008

```
WITH records
AS
(
  SELECT  Sequence,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sequence ASC) rn
  FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  a.Sequence, b.Sequence - 1 EndSequence
FROM    records a
        LEFT JOIN records b
          ON a.rn+1 = b.rn
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cabe1/6)

FOR SQL SERVER 2012

```
SELECT  SEQUENCE,
        LEAD(SEQUENCE) OVER (ORDER BY SEQUENCE) - 1 EndSequence
FROM    TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cabe1/5)

Comment: Nice use of the new 2012 LEAD keyword

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table to itself, where the condition in the join is to match records in the right side greater than the value of records in the left side. Then group by the value on the left side and aggregate for the smallest value on the right:

```
SELECT l.Sequence, MIN(r.Seqence)-1 "EndSequence"
FROM table l
LEFT JOIN table r ON r.Sequence > l.Sequence
GROUP BY l.Sequence
```