# How to update from other table based on sequence?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I've managed to get this: 
[How to get the end of entry of the first column in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195154/how-to-get-the-end-of-entry-of-the-first-column-in-tsql)

The updated data as follow and managed to get the last record as well updated.

```
Service; Sequence; EndSequence  
A, 2089697; 2089737
B, 2089738; 2089837
C, 2089838; 2090367
D, 2090368; 2090399
E, 2090400; 2090500
```

Now I want to update the master table which has million records on it based on the sequence start and end start on the ID. I can do this via cursor but I prefer via normal query.

BTW I'm using SQL 2005.

The Master table as follow:

```
ID; Value; Service
2089697; 23; null
...
2090500; 12; null
```

so the result will be:

```
ID; Value; Service
2089697; 23; A
... 
2089737; 45; A
2089738; 45; B
...
2089837; 34; B 
2089838; 23; C
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

More than one option here.

1. Correlated subquery:

   ```
   UPDATE MasterTable
   SET Service = (
     SELECT s.Service
     FROM SequenceTable s
     WHERE MasterTable.ID BETWEEN s.Sequence AND s.EndSequence
   )
   WHERE Service IS NULL
   ;
   ```
2. Inner join:

   ```
   UPDATE MasterTable
   SET Service = s.Service
   FROM SequenceTable s
   WHERE MasterTable.Service IS NULL
     AND MasterTable.ID BETWEEN s.Sequence AND s.EndSequence
   ;
   ```

   Alternative syntax:

   ```
   UPDATE m
   SET Service = s.Service
   FROM MasterTable m
   INNER JOIN SequenceTable s
     ON m.ID BETWEEN s.Sequence AND s.EndSequence
   WHERE m.Service IS NULL
   ;
   ```

Both options assume that the ranges in `SequenceTable` do not overlap.